# If a javascript module is null, will its listeners be cleaned

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript module setup like the following:

```
var Accordion = (function ($){

    Accordion = function(container,item_name,space){

        this.container = container;
        this.item = item_name;

        /**
         * Event Listeners
         */
        $("#up").click(function(){

        });
    }

    return Accordion;
})(jQuery);
```

And is instantiated like:

```
var my_module = new Accordion('blah','blah','blah');
```

Will doing `my_module = null;` remove the click event?

Comment: I don't think so. But why not just try it yourself? Put a console.log in the click function, and see if it still logs after you set it to null.

Comment: @Adam simple answer is "no", not if the anything holds a reference, including everything in the DOM.

Comment: I think what you can do is on my_module = null. You can perform $("#element").children().off();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not.  [The click event is actually stored as a listener for the element, using `addEventListener`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0c466438d1feaec302fec13eafeeb063bbfd6a19/src/event.js#L123-L125) - when you null out `my_module` you simply null out the object returned from your `Accordian` constructor.  The click handler remains associated with the *still existing* DOM node with the ID `up`.

To remove the handler, add a `destroy` method to your accordian and call that:

```
var Accordion = (function ($){

  var Accordion = function(container,item_name,space){

    function upClickHandler(){}
    this.container = container;
    this.item = item_name;

    $("#up").click(upClickHandler);

    this.destroy = function Accordian$destroy() {
      $("#up").off("click", upClickHandler);
    };
  }

  return Accordion;
})(jQuery);
```

Then, you can call `my_module.destroy()` to remove the listener and do any other cleanup.